# What is the proper way to execute axios / firebase promises in a specific order in a firebase function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, axios

What is the best way to chain axios / firebase promises that must be linked in a specific order and use the returns of previous promises?

I am writing a firebase function that allows me to update a user via a third-party JWT API. So I have to fulfill several promises (I use axios for that) to build the final query with a uid, a token and a refresh token.

**These requests must be executed in the right order, each promise waiting for the result of the previous one to be able to execute.**

1. recover the firebase client token to identify the user
2. search in a collection for the tokens (access & refresh) that were previously stored and associated with the user's uid.
3. Execute the "me" request on the third-party API to retrieve the user's information and update the user.

**My question: What is the most correct way to chase these axios promises?**

For the moment, I have managed to achieve this result, by interlocking the calls successively to properly manage the "catch" and by moving in separate functions the calls to make a little more digest the reading of the code.

```
/* index.js */

const userModule = require('./user');

exports.me = functions.https.onRequest( (request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
        let idToken = request.body.data.token;

        userModule
            .get(idToken)
            .then((uid) => {
                console.log('User found : ' + uid);
                return userModule
                    .retrieve(uid)
                    .then((userTokens) => {
                        console.log('User tokens found : ' + userTokens.token);
                        return userModule
                            .me(userTokens.token, uid)
                            .then((me) => {
                                return me;
                            }).catch((error) => {
                                return response.status(404).json({
                                    data : {
                                        error : 404,
                                        message : 'NO_USER_ON_API'
                                    }
                                });
                            })
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                        return response.status(404).json({
                            data : {
                                error : 404,
                                message : 'NO_TOKEN_USER_FOUND'
                            }
                        });
                    })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                return response.status(500).json({
                    data : {
                        error : 500,
                        message : 'USER_TOKEN_NO_MATCH'
                    }
                });
            })
            .then((user) => {
                if(user.data !== undefined)
                {
                    return response.status(200).json({
                        data : {
                            user : user.data
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    return response.status(204).json({
                        data : {
                            user : null
                        }
                    });
                }
            })

    });
});
```

```
/* user.js */

exports.get = (firebaseToken) {

    return admin.auth().verifyIdToken(firebaseToken)
        .then(function(decodedToken) {
            return decodedToken.uid;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            throw {
                code: 500,
                body: "INTERNAL_ERROR"
            };
        });

};

exports.retrieve = (uid) {
    return admin.firestore().collection("AccessTokenCollection").doc(uid).get()
        .then(function(docRef) {
            return docRef.data();
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            throw {
                code: 404,
                body: "NO_USER_FOUND"
            };
        });

};

exports.me = (UserToken, uid) {

    let params = {
        params: {
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + UserToken
        }
    };

    return axiosInstance.instance.get(url + '/users/me', params)
        .then(userMe => {
            return userMe;
        })
        .catch(errMe => {
            console.log(errMe.response.status);

            throw {
                code: 401,
                body: "EXPIRING_TOKEN"
            };
        });

};

Etc...
```

The code works as it is more a theoretical question or optimization!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const userModule = require('./user');

exports.me = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, async () => {
    let idToken = request.body.data.token;
    try {
      let uid = await userModule.get(idToken);
      console.log('User found : ' + uid);
      let userTokens = await userModule.retrieve(uid);
      console.log('User tokens found : ' + userTokens.token);
      let meObj = await userModule.me(userTokens.token, uid);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  });
});
```

So, here using async-await i have removed then-catch block. `await` keyword will work as `then` and will only move forward to second call after first call has been completed. And i have made a common catch block for error handling which you can modified according to your needs

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use promise.all and async-await instead of then and catch

Comment: Can you give me an example of structuring?  It seemed to me that promise.all allowed to run queries in parallel in a specific order, in my case I can not run them in parallel because I need the answer of the first to launch the next one.  I do not see how to use promise.all.  I am interested in an example, perhaps async/await do the trick ?